# How to pass info depending on which button is pressed?

Tags: button, callback, flutter, parameter-passing

I now understand how to get the right button to take the right action (from your help). I'm still confused abut how to get ("$a + $b = ") to screen2 - where I will have a keyboard to type the answer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Sigh",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: MyHome(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => MyHome(),
        //     '/screen2': (BuildContext context) => MyOutput(),  supposed to be the keyboardscreen.
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  final random = Random();

  int a, b, sum;
  String output;

  void changeData() {
    setState(() {
      a = random.nextInt(10);
      b = random.nextInt(10);

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void handleButtonPressed(String buttonName) {
    if (buttonName == '+') {
      sum = a + b;
      output = '$a + $b =';
    } else if (buttonName == '-') {
      if (a >= b) {
        sum = a - b;
        output = "$a - $b =";
      } else if (b > a) {  //sum cannot be negative here
        sum = b - a;
        output = "$b - $a =";
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SIGH"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("+"),
              onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
            handleButtonPressed('+');
          }, //how can I get the output to my keyboardscreen?
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("-"),
              onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
            handleButtonPressed('-');
          },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyOutput extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(""),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the question but just passing a value that identifies the pressed button should do:

```
FlatButton(..., onPressed: () => handleButtonPressed('+'),
FlatButton(..., onPressed: () => handleButtonPressed('-'),

...

void handleButtonPressed(String buttonName) {
  if(buttonName == '+') { ... }
  else if(...) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For understanding which button pressed you should use variable that storing current operation state.

For example, variable `curOperationState` that have two states `OperationType.plus` and `OperationType.minus`. When you pressed plus button equate `curOperationState=OperationType.plus;`, when you pressed minus button equate `curOperationState=OperationType.minus;`.

Later you just need to check what current state of `curOperationState` variable.

For checking use this: `if (curOperationState == OperationType.plus) { ...`

Code of use:

```
...

enum OperationType {plus, minus}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {

  OperationType curOperationState = OperationType.minus;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('+'),
                onPressed: (() {
                  curOperationState = OperationType.plus;
                }),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('-'),
                onPressed: (() {
                  curOperationState = OperationType.minus;
                }),
              )
            ],
          ),
    );
  }
...
```

Hope it helps, Good Luck!